# Unable to connect to Power bi using restapi?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to send POST request to

https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token to get authorization code with parameters inside the body:

```
{  
   "grant_type":"password",
   "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "resource":"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
   "username":"xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
   "password":"xxxxxxx",
   "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I am getting error:

> { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "AADSTS90014: The
>   request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'. Trace
>   ID: 6725893b-5f12-4f6b-9334-ea6c86f10400 Correlation ID:
>   27f51716-70fb-45f0-85d5-4ccfb32390c2 Timestamp: 2018-10-16 12:21:04Z",
>   "error_codes": [   90014 ], "timestamp": "2018-10-16 12:21:04Z",
>   "trace_id": "6725893b-5f12-4f6b-9334-ea6c86f10400", "correlation_id":
>   "27f51716-70fb-45f0-85d5-4ccfb32390c2" }

what should be given as resource paramter?

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I googled your error code (AADSTS90014) and found a lot of posts on the topic.   At a glance, I would try the solution at the bottom of this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d54c668f-d8e3-4662-b124-d9abc3176c8c/http-post-body-parameters-to-get-oauth2-token?forum=azurelogicapps

I would have left this as a comment but I'm still short of the 50 required reputation points.

Thanks

Comment: can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/52908864/10512791 @HeavyDNickell