# Get Power Bi report data in Json format using RESTAPI?

Tags: powerbi

I want to read data of report on the server,there are api calls to get list of reports(GET api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports{reportKey}),In the same way can get data of a report in json format using restapi?

Comment: Are you asking "how to publish  PowerBI report" as JSON data?

Comment: I want to read data of report on the server,there are api calls to get list of reports(GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportKey}),Is there any way we can get data of a report in json format @RomanPokrovskij

Comment: with above get request url we only get details about the report, I want to get data of the report,Is it possible? @RomanPokrovskij

Comment: edit your question mentioning this API

Comment: Can you look at this question also? @RomanPokrovskij  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835441/10512791

Answer (score 0):

I think in a word **"No"**.   At least not from what I am reading from the API Endpoints documentation here:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

In the end -- I think what you really want is the data behind the report, not the visualizations - Right?   Power Query is an Excel based tool (from Microsoft) that retrieves data much in the same way Power BI does.    I think that may be what you want.

If you really need a JSON representation of the data from there, you can do a little "VBA" work to reformat the data you pulled in via Power Query.

Hope this helps

Comment: for tableau i am able to get data in the form of Json@HevyDNickell