# Unable to get list of datasets in power bi using RestApi?

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyusA.png)After getting Access token, by sending GET request to

```
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/datasets/
```

by adding access token in header

content-type: application/json
authorization: access token

instead of getting datasets i am getting html content below:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
>     <head>
>         <title>Power BI</title>
>         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
> 
>         <meta charset="utf-8">
>         <meta name="description" content="">
>         <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
>         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/PowerBI_Favicon.ico" />
>         
>     <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=929738808">
>     <meta name="apple-itunes-app-tab" content="app-id=929738808">
>     <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.microsoft.powerbim">
>     <meta name="google-play-app-tab" content="app-id=com.microsoft.powerbim">
>     <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on"> .............
```

how to get list of datasets in json format?

code(java sdk):

```
    String workspacename = "rightws";
    String username = "xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    String workspaceId = "xxxxxxxxxxx1-9812b695603a";
    String reportId="6xxxxxxxxxx4098-a55b-96f8c103edab";
    String accessKey = "xxxxx34d7f7xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    PowerBIToken token = PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken(
            workspacename,
            workspaceId,
            reportId,
            username,
            null);
    String jwt = token.Generate(accessKey);
```

System.out.println(jwt);

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be using the wrong endpoint. The documentation for the Rest API is here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets

To get a list of data sets you either need to use this endpoint  (note there is no "group" designation in URL)

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets
```

Or this one (which is data sets for a specific group -- group ID is required)

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets
```

You appear to be using the endpoint that returns groups.  I think "/me/datasets" must be getting ignored

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i am getting 403 error when sending get request to api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets with header as authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx , content-type:appl/json @HeavyDNickell

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(responseContent, "Get Datasets");
            }
        }
```

If you keep getting 403 error, then make sure you granted rights to read datasets when you register your application. Try to decode the access token at https://jwt.io and see does it contains Dataset.Read.All in scp:

[image]

UPDATE: It looks like your token doesn't give you rights to get the list of datasets. Try to register a new native application and make sure you select "Read All Datasets" checkbox from Dataset APIs. Then try to obtain the access token with code like this:

```
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
string clientId = "xxxxxx";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, new TokenCache());
var authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
if (authenticationResult != null)
    GetListOfDatasets(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
```

UPDATE: To list datasets using the Power BI Client library, you need code like this. First you need to authenticate using AcquireTokenAsync (either providing user name and password, or be prompted interactively), then pass this access token to your client and call GetDatasetsInGroupWithHttpMessageAsync method.

```
private static string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
private static string apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com";
private static string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static string groupId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

UserPasswordCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential("someuser@example.com", "some strong password");
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, uc).Result;
TokenCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials($"{authenticationResult.AccessToken}", "Bearer");
using (var client = new Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), credentials))
{
    var resultDatasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(groupId);
    foreach (var item in resultDatasets.Body.Value)
        MessageBox.Show($"{item.Name} ({item.Id})");
}
```

Comment: I dont find scp in the decoded token @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: How do you obtained this token? Could you provide the decoded payload here for reviewing it (deleting the sensitive parts, of course)?

Comment: {
  "aud": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1540992342,
  "nbf": 1540992342,
  "exp": 1540996242,
  "aio": "42RgYEg+YDnZ4Man88dERJepCbToAQA=",
  "appid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "tid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "uti": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ver": "1.0"
} @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: Is this token generated using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)? Check App registrations in Azure AD does your app has access to Power BI Service API and which are the delegated permissions? Eventually, try to grant permissions for it.But essentially, you are getting 403 because this token doesn't give you rights to read the list of datasets.

Comment: please check the image attached, i got the token by sending post request tohttps://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: Try to obtain the token with the sample code that I added to my answer instead.

Comment: is there a java version of the code you have attached? @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: Yes. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries#microsoft-supported-client-libraries) is the list of supported clients and you can get the Java client from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:adal4j%20g:com.microsoft.azure).

Comment: Actually i am developing code in java can you help me with the java version of the code ? Andrey Nikolov

Comment: I'm not Java developer, but it should be as simple as instantiating AuthenticationContext class and calling acquireToken method. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.aad.adal4j._authentication_context.acquiretoken?view=azure-java-stable) is the reference and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) are the samples.

Comment: https://github.com/m-moris/PowerBI-SDK-Java what is access key where will i find it? @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: This must be a legacy concept from Workspace collections. Try to pass null there. It has default null value, so you may not need it at all now.

Comment: can you check code i have added under( java sdk) , i got access token still i am not able to find **scp** in payload is it because of free trial @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: Your code generates [Embed Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken) which is used to get access for this particular report only. You can't use it for Rest API service calls, like listing datasets. I will update my answer with sample C# code how to do this, which you can translate to Java.

Comment: I don't find UserPasswordCredentials or any jar files related to add to my project @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: I'm not Java developer, but from one quick look at this Java client, it looks quite outdated. I do not believe it represents the current state of the C# client. It has no new commits for more than 2 years. If you can't find a decent Java client, you should simply use [ADAL for Java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/) and pure [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) calls.

Comment: Is it possible to read data behind the report using .net sdk? @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: With the update .net code you have given when tried getting 401 error, where should we give client secret @Andrey Nikolov