# Is there a java sdk for accessing power bi reports?

Tags: java, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have few reports on power bi report server, I want to access reports data using java sdk or restapi? Is there a java sdk available?

Comment: Seems like Power BI has a REST API that you can use - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

Comment: Can you look into this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52927800/10512791 @Dan W

Comment: No. I'm not sure your requirements so I will not look at random links to help solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/), but it does not provide you a way to get the data from a dataset. You should go to the source, from which the data is loaded. Using the REST API you can [get information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasetbyid#datasource) about it, but you will need rights to access it (e.g. credentials).